# Spring "Failed to bind properties under..." on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring, kubernetes, yaml, cloud, config

I've got a problem with my spring configuration on kubernetes.

I have given yaml configuration for my spring boot application.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: "Application name"
  banner:
    location: classpath:banner.txt
server:
  port: 8081

some:
  data:
    active: true
# other data
```

So I created a ConfigMap for my app in that way

```
kubectl create --save-config configmap spring-application-config --from-file=application.yml --namespace dev -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl apply -f -
```

But unfortunately I receive that error from spring:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'some' to my.app.ApplicationConfig:
```

I've checked ApplicationConfig class and every property is mapped properly and also tested it locally and this problem only appears on kubernetes.

Comment: You have created a configMap. But did you make your pod use that configMap?

Comment: Yes. I also modified the config file and then I was getting an error with new value so I'm sure that Spring can read config file. It's all about the parsing.

Comment: How are you using this config in your `ApplicationConfig`class? Can you please show it?
Because it looks like you are trying to bind to a wrong field.
Also, a Kubernetes deployment file for the application might help.